# Fritz 18 Position Setup For Engine Match

Tags: opening, engines, tournament, fritz

The other day, I saw a GothamChess on two engines playing the King's Gambit. I thought to myself that it would be interesting to do the same thing, so I tried it in Fritz 18. I know that I have to store a position in a database define the database that I want them to play in the openings tab, but I don't know how to do so. If I try, then the engines simply play from the starting position instead of playing from the selected position. Am I doing anything wrong? Please help.